# Netbeans splash screen not working

Tags: java, netbeans, splash-screen

I have an application that I want to add a splash screen GIF to. To do so I did the following:

- Add the path to the splash img in the project run settings 
  -splash:src/images/SplashImage.gif
- I added the following line in the manifest file: 
  SplashScreen-Image: images/SplashImage.gif
- Added thread.sleep to the Main class so it shows up

My problem is that I added the Splash Screen and it worked, but when I decided to change it to a different one, using the same steps, the Splash Screen won't show up. I tried setting the splach screen to PNGs and JPGs to see if they worked and I had the same problem. Occasionally an image would work, but if I try to change it to another then the new one won't show up. At this point I'm just waiting it out hoping one of my attempts will go through, but as it is adding a splash screen has turned from a 1-2 hr job to a week long headache.

Comment: Are you taking care to be sure that your `Thread.sleep(...)` being called off of the Swing event thread?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that. I don't see how that would differ from case to case. If I have a splash image, let's call it splash_1.gif, and it works then it will work forever. The problem is if I wan't to make a change to it. Let's say I go and change the color of the background and now I have splash_2.gif then when I try to add this splash then chances are it doesn't work. What I have done so far is keep making copies (splash_3, splash_4...etc) and I try to add those until one finally works but sometimes this can take days.

Comment: @dave : Maybe my answer [Changing SplashScreen Image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23284181/1322642) can help you !